# Assistance with Join Optimization in Oracle

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, inner-join

I'm fairly new to SQL and programming in general and I need help with the following query. It executes for hours and ends up in a timeout/connection closed.

I have tried creating composite indexes for all of the tables involved in the join, but it doesn't seem to help at all, which is strange.

This query used to run just fine, but the hang up started occuring after I added a condition to the join with `Lods_F_D_O_Dlvr_Dtil` table (it is the commented line). What do you suggest I do to improve performance? Thanks :c)

```
Select 
        A1.Dcmt_Nmbr, 
        A3.Blng_Nmbr, 
        T5.Shpm_Nmbr, 
        T6.Splr_Code, 
        T6.Splr_Name, 
        A6.Cnpj_Cpf_Nmbr, 
        a7.cnpj_cpf_nmbr, 
        A5.ordr_rson_code
From Lods_F_D_F_Nota_Fisc A1
  Inner Join Lods_F_D_F_Nota_Fisc_Item A2 On A1.Dcmt_Nmbr = A2.Dcmt_Nmbr
  Inner Join Lods_F_D_F_Blng_Item A3      On A3.Blng_Nmbr = A2.Srce_Dcmt_Code
                                          And A3.Item_Nmbr = A2.Item_Nmbr 
  Inner Join Lods_F_D_S_Sles_Ordr_Item A4 On A4.Sles_Dcmt_Nmbr = A3.Sles_Dcmt_Nmbr
                                          And A4.Item_Nmbr = A3.Item_Dcmt_Sles
  Inner Join Lods_F_D_s_Sles_Ordr A5      on a5.sles_dcmt_nmbr = a4.sles_dcmt_nmbr
  inner Join Lods_F_D_O_Dlvr_Dtil T3      On T3.Sles_Dcmt_Nmbr=A4.Sles_Dcmt_Nmbr
                                          And T3.Item_Nmbr = A4.Item_Nmbr
                                          --AND T3.DLVR_NMBR=A3.DLVR_NMBR
  inner Join Lods_F_D_O_Dlvr T4           On T4.Dlvr_Nmbr=T3.Dlvr_Nmbr
  inner Join Lods_F_D_O_Shpm T5           On T5.Shpm_Nmbr=T4.Shpm_Nmbr
  Inner Join Lods_M_Plnt A6               On A6.Plnt_Code = A4.Plnt_Code
                                          And A6.End_Date is null
  Inner Join Lods_M_Cstm A7               On A7.Cstm_Code = A5.Cstm_Code
                                          and a7.end_date is null
  LEFT JOIN LODS_M_SPLR T6                ON T5.SPLR_CODE=T6.SPLR_CODE
                                          And T6.End_Date Is Null
group by 
        A1.Dcmt_Nmbr,
        A3.Blng_Nmbr,
        T5.Shpm_Nmbr,
        T6.Splr_Code,
        T6.Splr_Name,
        A6.Cnpj_Cpf_Nmbr,
        a7.cnpj_cpf_nmbr,
        A5.ordr_rson_code
```

This is the execution plan:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KW9h.png

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the EXPLAIN PLAN as I am at work and images are blocked. However I have a litlle idea of what's going on.

Your problematic JOIN is referering multiple tables : T3, A3, A4.

```
  inner Join Lods_F_D_O_Dlvr_Dtil T3  On T3.Sles_Dcmt_Nmbr=A4.Sles_Dcmt_Nmbr
                                      And T3.Item_Nmbr = A4.Item_Nmbr
                                      AND T3.DLVR_NMBR=A3.DLVR_NMBR
```

This is allowed, but is a perf killer on large tables and/or with a lot of jointures like you have. Oracle's optimiser hates that kind of stuff as it can't really determine the right path and indexes to use, and thus end up in a full table(s) scan.

At first glance I would propose to move the T3/A3 comparaison in the WHERE clause, so it is executed after all the jointures happens. This turns the query into something different and might or might not return the expected results, but give it a try:

```
Select 
        A1.Dcmt_Nmbr, 
        A3.Blng_Nmbr, 
        T5.Shpm_Nmbr, 
        T6.Splr_Code, 
        T6.Splr_Name, 
        A6.Cnpj_Cpf_Nmbr, 
        a7.cnpj_cpf_nmbr, 
        A5.ordr_rson_code
From Lods_F_D_F_Nota_Fisc A1
  Inner Join Lods_F_D_F_Nota_Fisc_Item A2 On A1.Dcmt_Nmbr = A2.Dcmt_Nmbr
  Inner Join Lods_F_D_F_Blng_Item A3      On A3.Blng_Nmbr = A2.Srce_Dcmt_Code
                                          And A3.Item_Nmbr = A2.Item_Nmbr 
  Inner Join Lods_F_D_S_Sles_Ordr_Item A4 On A4.Sles_Dcmt_Nmbr = A3.Sles_Dcmt_Nmbr
                                          And A4.Item_Nmbr = A3.Item_Dcmt_Sles
  Inner Join Lods_F_D_s_Sles_Ordr A5      on a5.sles_dcmt_nmbr = a4.sles_dcmt_nmbr
  inner Join Lods_F_D_O_Dlvr_Dtil T3      On T3.Sles_Dcmt_Nmbr=A4.Sles_Dcmt_Nmbr
                                          And T3.Item_Nmbr = A4.Item_Nmbr
  inner Join Lods_F_D_O_Dlvr T4           On T4.Dlvr_Nmbr=T3.Dlvr_Nmbr
  inner Join Lods_F_D_O_Shpm T5           On T5.Shpm_Nmbr=T4.Shpm_Nmbr
  Inner Join Lods_M_Plnt A6               On A6.Plnt_Code = A4.Plnt_Code
                                          And A6.End_Date is null
  Inner Join Lods_M_Cstm A7               On A7.Cstm_Code = A5.Cstm_Code
                                          and a7.end_date is null
  LEFT JOIN LODS_M_SPLR T6                ON T5.SPLR_CODE=T6.SPLR_CODE
                                          And T6.End_Date Is Null

WHERE T3.DLVR_NMBR=A3.DLVR_NMBR
group by 
        A1.Dcmt_Nmbr,
        A3.Blng_Nmbr,
        T5.Shpm_Nmbr,
        T6.Splr_Code,
        T6.Splr_Name,
        A6.Cnpj_Cpf_Nmbr,
        a7.cnpj_cpf_nmbr,
        A5.ordr_rson_code
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, when I added the condition to the WHERE clause I got the following error:

SQL Error: ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM

How can I solve this?